# Python 3 dict KeyError with right hash

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, hash, key

I'm completely stuck with this problem. This seems impossible to me, but it is really happening.

**Description of the bug**

Let's say I'm using an object of hashable class Key to store objects of class Value in a python 3 native dict. For now the dict contains only one key and one value.

When later in the program I try to retrieve the value v1 with key k1 (`d[k1]`), I get a KeyError. It happends and does not need a question here. But :

**What I tried so far**

I used the debugger console of PyDev to inspect the variables and find the bug.
Just after the allocation `d[k1] = v1` I can access v1 without problem.

Where the bug happens, I retrieved the key using `k2 = list(dict)[0]`. Then, even with k2 from the dict I got the same KeyError when doing `d[k2]` !

- just in case : `type(d)` => class 'dict'
- same hashes: `hash(k1)` equals `hash(k2)` => -6069959488783444446
- equals : `k1.__equals__(k2)` and `k1 == k2` => True

Try some other stuff:

- `d[list(d)[0]]` raises a KeyError
- `for k in d: print(d[k])` raises a KeyError

Weird, looks like the dict is corrupted or something like that... but:

- `for k, v in d.items(): print(k, v)` works perfectly well !

And if I do:

```
d2 = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    d2[k] = v
```

Then `d2[k1]` and `d2[k2]` work well too.

Someone ever faced that kind of problem ? I'm completely out of ideas...

Comment: Consider rereading [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and   provide code respecting [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without your code and the data you are operating on its kindof difficult to help out.

Comment: Hi, I cannot myself reproduce the bug in a small snippet to share with you yet.

Comment: Are you sure that `for k in d: print(d[k])` raises `KeyError`? If so, something is awfully wrong with the implementation of your class and we can't help you unless you share some actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I completely failed in the implementation of the Key **hash**() method. I returned a different hash when the attributes where changed (the object is mutable) !

I solved it but using the id() function in **hash**().

Hash mismatch ! ;)